# perl plotting for multiple datasets in .csv file

Tags: perl, csv, gnuplot, text-processing

I have a .csv file with the following data.(I open CSV file as comma separated file)

```
file1 date1  1  76.09
      date10 10 87.09
      date11 11 89.89
      date2  2  66.5
      date3  3  78.89
      date4  4  87.98
      date5  5  57
      date6  6  57.98
      date7  7  34.32
      date8  8  45.76
      date9  9  34.99
file2 date1  1  82.45
      date2  2  86.23
file3 date1  1  65.76
      date10 10 34.89
      date11 11 23.79
      date12 12 86.23
      date2  2  23.78
      date3  3  45.78
      date4  4  34.78
      date5  5  67.89
      date6  6  34.78
      date7  7  78.45
      date8  8  67.89
      date9  9  86.23
```

Now I want to know how to plot a graph for each of these datasets file1,file2,file3 with column3 as X axis and column 4 as Y axis.

What I do right now is, I manually copy paste data for each file and use GNUPLOT like

```
plot  "data.csv" using 1:2 title 'file1'
```

But I want to do it in a perl script and want to use perl plotting. Also is there a way which can save me from manually copy pasting data for each file into separate csv file everytime I plot the graph.

Thanks for your help.

Thank you.