# perl plotting using GD:Graph

Tags: perl, graph, plot

I have data like this.

```
file1 date1  1  76.09
      date10 10 87.09
      date11 11 89.89
      date2  2  66.5
      date3  3  78.89
      date4  4  87.98
      date5  5  57
      date6  6  57.98
      date7  7  34.32
      date8  8  45.76
      date9  9  34.99
file2 date1  1  82.45
      date2  2  86.23
file3 date1  1  65.76
      date10 10 34.89
      date11 11 23.79
      date12 12 86.23
      date2  2  23.78
      date3  3  45.78
      date4  4  34.78
      date5  5  67.89
      date6  6  34.78
      date7  7  78.45
      date8  8  67.89
      date9  9  86.23
```

I am storing the column 3 and column 4 values in array.

```
@x = [1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
and corresponding column 4 values in array @y
```

Now I plot the graph as folllows:

```
my @data = ([@x], [@y]);

my $mygraph = GD::Graph::lines->new(500, 300);
$mygraph->set(
                        x_label     => 'X axis',
                        y_label     => 'Y axis',
                        title       => "stats",
                    ) or warn $mygraph->error;

 my $myimage = $mygraph->plot(\@data) or die $mygraph->error;
```

My problem is...

In the graph the X-axis has values displayed as 1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and corresponding y values plotted. I cannot hard code the x -axis values as I extract these data from a file into these arrays. How do I make sure that X-axis has values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 and has corresponding y values plotted.

Also I have abother file which has data like:

```
file1 date1  1  1
      date10 10 2
      date11 11 2
      date2  2  2
      date3  3  3
      date4  4  3
      date5  5  3
      date6  6  4
      date7  7  4
      date8  8  4
      date9  9  4
file2 date1  1  3
      date2  2  2
file3 date1  1  2
      date10 10 3
      date11 11 3
      date12 12 3
      date2  2  3
      date3  3  1
      date4  4  2
      date5  5  5
      date6  6  1
      date7  7  1
      date8  8  2
      date9  9  2
```

I can plot graohs for datasets in both of these files separately.
But what I want to do is, I want to show a single graph with column 3 and column 4 of first file plotted along with the column 3 and column 4 of 2nd file plotted in single graph.

Can somebody please help me with these two issues.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Also even though you are using `GD::Graph::lines`, your discussion make me think that you don't want the kind of line graphs that `GD::Graph` produces by default. Rather, you seem to want X-Y scatter plots. But I'm not sure I understand your goal. If you do want scatter plots, see `GD::Graph::Cartesian`.

Comment: sorry. I would make it clear.
I am plotting a line graph for each of the dataset in 2 files.I have a line graph plotted for file1 from first file,a graph plotted for file2 from first file,and one for file3 from first file.

Similarly, I have a line graph plotted for each of file1,file2,file3 of second file.

I want to combine the graphs for file1 from both first and second file so that I can correlate the data and do some analysis. It can look like anything but there should be way to see both data in same graph. I am not particular about using any specific kind of graph.

Comment: -1: you posted almost this exact question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269355/perl-plotting-for-multiple-datasets-in-csv-file/3269598#3269598 2 days ago, to which I offered a solution and you haven't closed, accepted or otherwise acknowledged it.

Comment: @Pedo merged.  jerrygo, welcome, and take a day to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: sorry. I would take care of it from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another try. I won't use `GD::Graph`, as I've already began this answer in your other post with `Graphics::GnuplotIF`.

Your two problems, as I understand them, are:

1. You want to numerically sort the x-values.
2. You want to plot multiple series.

Right:

```
use Graphics::GnuplotIF;

my $last;
my %data_per_file;

LOAD:
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($file, $label, $x, $y) = split /\s+/;
    $last = $file if $file;
    push @{$data_per_file{$last}}, [$label, $x, $y];
}

SORT:
for my $file (keys %data_per_file) {
    @{$data_per_file{$file}}
    = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
      @{$data_per_file{$file}};
}

my @all_data_in_pairs;

PLOT_SINGLE:
for my $file (keys %data_per_file) {
    my @labels = map { $_->[0] } @{$data_per_file{$file}};
    my @x      = map { $_->[1] } @{$data_per_file{$file}};
    my @y      = map { $_->[2] } @{$data_per_file{$file}};

    my $plot = Graphics::GnuplotIF->new(persist => 1, style => 'points');
    $plot->gnuplot_set_title( $file );
    $plot->gnuplot_plot_xy( \@x, \@y );

    push @all_data_in_pairs, \@x, \@y;
}

my $plot = Graphics::GnuplotIF->new(persist => 1, style => 'lines');
$plot->gnuplot_set_xrange(0, 10);
$plot->gnuplot_hardcopy( 'output.ps',
                         'postscript',
                         'color lw 3' )
if $want_hardcopy;

$plot->gnuplot_set_title( 'all' );
$plot->gnuplot_plot_many( @all_data_in_pairs );

$plot->gnuplot_restore_terminal();
```

Comment: I am sorry for that. I tried using Graphics::GnuplotIF; for 2 days but was stuck with some errors and I posted a comment to the old post 21 hours ago. As I am new to perl, I do not know much on how to solve that problem. Am still searching for it. So I thought of using GD: Graph and was able to make some progress with it. Sorry for posting the question again, but this time I posted as I had to do using perl plot and had to add whatever I did till now.

Sorry all for my mistake. I will take care from next time.

Answer (score 0):

**Post merged. Updated version at [perl plotting using GD:Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285340/perl-plotting-using/3287615#3287615).**

Perl doesn't have 'native' plotting facilities: you'll have to use an external library, so you might as well use `gnuplot` if available. There are [plenty](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=gnuplot&mode=all) of interfaces to `gnuplot` on `CPAN`. One that I've used and seems to work well is [Graphics::GnuplotIF](http://search.cpan.org/~mehner/Graphics-GnuplotIF-1.5/lib/Graphics/GnuplotIF.pm).

You could do something like the following:

```
use Graphics::GnuplotIF;

my $last;
my %data_per_file;

LOAD:
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($file, $label, $x, $y) = split /\s+/;
    $last = $file if $file;
    push @{$data_per_file{$last}}, [$label, $x, $y];
}

PLOT:
for my $file (keys %data_per_file) {
    my @labels = map { $_->[0] } @{$data_per_file{$file}};
    my @x      = map { $_->[1] } @{$data_per_file{$file}};
    my @y      = map { $_->[2] } @{$data_per_file{$file}};

    my $plot = Graphics::GnuplotIF->new(persist => 1, style => 'points');
    $plot->gnuplot_set_title( $file );
    $plot->gnuplot_plot_xy( \@x, \@y );
}
```

Comment: am getting an error 
"problem closing communication to gnuplot"

can somebody help me how to solve this.

Comment: That sometimes happens when the destructor doesn't cleanly close the pipe to `gnuplot` or the file to which it printed the hardcopy. It should be harmless, as the error is only invoked during the object destruction phase. In any case, it's odd you're getting the error; I'm not. Did you try the updated version (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285340/perl-plotting-using/3287615#3287615)?

Comment: Yes I did. But the problem is..I get the error again. Also,I am not able to see any graph.